# Valid HTTP-Post doesn't work in android

Tags: android, http

I've got the following code for sending data via HTTP Post. When I send a http post via RESTCLIENT (Chrome extension), the data is correctly transmitted and stored in a MySQL database. But when I send the data via my android service, nothing arrives.

```
private HttpClient mHttpClient;
private HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost("http:/.../main.php");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mId", "\"" + getId() + "\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server", "\"localhost\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "\"xxx\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "\"xxx\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("debug", "\"true\""));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", "\"" + formatterStartTime.format(startTime) + "\""));
            mHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            Log.i("HRV", "insert measure: " + nameValuePairs.toString());

            HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
            response.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

Edit: http://pastebin.com/FgA4TLgB log output after sending http post

Edit2: I'm checking internet connection with this method

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

I also have the following code in the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.hsn.hrv.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.hsn.hrv.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="de.hsn.hrv.app.PreferenceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_preference" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name="de.hsn.hrv.service.BluetoothHandlerService"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The code for sending the http post lies in the service.

Comment: Is there any exception log?

Comment: No, as I said, there is nothing I can see. See http://pastebin.com/FgA4TLgB (log output after sending http post)

Comment: Must check that internet is available at that time in your device.

Comment: Running on local? Make sure that server is running. Also, check if server can connect DB without any problem. I can't see any problem in Android code.

Comment: The web server is at home, availible via DynDns. Currently I'm at work. When I use Advanced Rest Client (chrome extension for sending http request), the data is transmitted. The http variable "server" is used by the php script on the webservice. Also I can call the http address via browser. It must be somehting very stupid...

Answer (score 0):

I use Volley for REST API calls it works perfectly with little effort in implementation in your case you need to use StringRequest. I used too apaches httpclient and your code is correct so the problem maybe not be there.